# Importing urllib2 fails in python 2.7

Tags: python, urllib2

When I try importing urllib2 ,  i get the following error

> ```
> import urllib2
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 94, in <module>
> import httplib
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 79, in <module>
> import mimetools
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/mimetools.py", line 6, in <module>
> import tempfile
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/tempfile.py", line 34, in <module>
> from random import Random as _Random
> ImportError: cannot import name Random
> ```

i know that there is no module called Random, but i did check urllib2.py  and there was code which imported Random.

I am using Python 2.7

Comment: Did you build python from source? Is it from a distribution package?

Comment: `Random` is part of the `random` module, it's the RNG base class.

Comment: I think i have fixed it , there was a file random.py in my pwd and that was causing all the trouble. Kind of stupid, now i think of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you have a `random.py` file or module on your pythonpath so python search in it to find `random.Random` (that exists on python2.7).

Comment: so how you fix that?

Comment: @AlesisJoan by renaming "your" random.py module in another name to avoid confusion

Comment: Thx. I did that, and kill python proccess but still happens.

Comment: maybe there is still a "random.pyc" file in the path, ensure you have cleaned it too

Comment: and that's true, there is a random.pyc in the folder